# Is double quotes equals NULL in PHP

Tags: php

Is `""` equals to `NULL` in PHP?

For example:
Is `($value == "")` equals to `($value == NULL)`?

Comment: no..............http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: `NULL == ""`. Try it.

Comment: NULL and double quotes are different

Comment: Here is answer: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

"" (the empty string) is not the same as `null`, but because of PHP's type coercion rules they may evaluate as equal in a loose comparison.

That is:

```
"" == null  // true
"" === null // false
```

There is [a complete list of type comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for both loose and strict comparisons in the PHP Manual

Answer (score 0):

Just look for yourself.

```
var_dump("" == NULL);  // <= true
var_dump("" === NULL); // <= false
```

They are [equal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), but not not identical.